# Apt-get install php5 do not work

Tags: php, linux, bash, debian, virtual-machine

I am installing php on my virtual machine. I use `apt-get install php5` but it throws this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5 libonig2 libqdbm14 php5-cli php5-common php5-json php5-readline
Suggested packages:
  php-pear php5-user-cache
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5 libonig2 libqdbm14 php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-json php5-readline
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 255 kB/5,401 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libonig2 amd64 5.9.5-3.2
  Could not connect to ftp.es.debian.org:80 (82.194.78.250). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libqdbm14 amd64 1.8.78-5+b1
  Unable to connect to ftp.es.debian.org:http:
Err http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main php5-json amd64 1.3.6-1
  Unable to connect to ftp.es.debian.org:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libo/libonig/libonig2_5.9.5-3.2_amd64.deb  Could not connect to ftp.es.debian.org:80 (82.194.78.250). - connect (111: Connection refused)

E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qdbm/libqdbm14_1.8.78-5+b1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ftp.es.debian.org:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php-json/php5-json_1.3.6-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ftp.es.debian.org:http:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have checked the sources.list file and is the following:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.5.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160604-15:31]/ jessie main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.5.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160604-15:31]/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

#jessie bug security fix

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

I also used the `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but still with this failures...

Finally I tried to install php7 with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

But the `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` command output this: `-bash: add-apt-repository: command not found`

I have searched for tips to solve boths but I did no find anything so I need some help to keep pushing this...

Thank you

Comment: this is better suited for http://serverfault.com/ , side note did you try the `--fix-missing` ?

Comment: Remove all `es.`?

Comment: @Maik, here's my repository where I keep as an example - Vagrantfile with provisioning php7, postgresql, mysql and etc. https://github.com/reillyethan/vagrant-sample Feel free to use it. If it helps you - upvote my comment.

Comment: @cmorrissey I tried `--fix-missing` but but bash says that command doesn't exist.
@Cyrus I tried to erase all the `.es` and it works!!! Seems like the spanish repository does not work properly, or does not have the php package... 
@reillyethan Thanks for the url, I will add this and use it to install php7. 

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spain debian repos is down NOW (often falls). Please, change to another respos,  for example:  ftp.pt.debian.org